# insert div inside a string after N word count without breaking html

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to insert an ad inside text paragraph.

So far I've written this ([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pv4m69jb/3/)):

```
$(function() {
  var $article   = $('#post-text').html();
  var totalChars = $article.length;
  var breakChars = 300;
  if (totalChars > breakChars) {
    console.log(totalChars);
    var insertChars    = (breakChars - 10) + (totalChars - breakChars) * 0.2;
    var insertIndex    = $article.indexOf(' ', insertChars);
    var $articleWithAd = $article.substr(0,insertIndex) + '<div id="adPlayer">bla bla</div><p>' + $article.substr(insertIndex + 1);
    $('#post-text').html($articleWithAd);
  }
});
```

I count total char length of the text. I set breakpoint which is minimum where I want to insert ad, for smaller texts I don't insert it at all.

I also use percentage algorithm to try to insert ad into different positions based on total count and min count.

This works perfectly except when I encounter html tags, as the fiddle case demonstrates if I insert into space between two classes `class="class class2"` all the hell breaks loose...

I want to use my code but improve it to ignore html tags.

any ideas?

Comment: Don't try to mess with the HTML. grab DOM nodes and look at them one by one

Comment: @mplungjan that means I won't have character level control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Substitute `.text()` for `.html()`. Also, `<div>` is not valid child element of `<p>` element, `<p>` is not valid child element of `<p>` element.

You can use `.contents()`, to iterate `.nodeValue` or `.innerHTML` of `.childNodes` of `#post-text`, when `insertIndex` is reached, break `for` loops which iterate nodes and text, use `.before()` to insert `$articleWithAd` before node where `insertText` is. Note substituted `<span>` element for `<p>` element at `$articleWithAd`.

```js
$(function() {
      var elem = $('#post-text');
      var $article = elem.text();
      var totalChars = $article.length;
      var breakChars = 300;
      if (totalChars > breakChars) {
        console.log(totalChars);
        var insertChars = (breakChars - 10) + (totalChars - breakChars) * 0.2;
        var insertIndex = $article.indexOf(' ', insertChars);
        var $articleWithAd = '<span id="adPlayer" style="background:green">'
                             + 'bla bla<span>&nbsp;';
        var curr = null,
          n = 0;
    
        function countChars(el) {
          var text = el.nodeValue || el.innerHTML;
          iterateText: for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
            ++n;
            if (n === insertIndex) {
              curr = el;
              break iterateText;
            }
          };
          return curr
        }

        var elems = elem.contents();

        iterateNodes : for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
          if (elems[i].childNodes.length) {
            for (var c = 0; c < elems[i].childNodes.length; c++) {
              if (countChars(elems[i].childNodes[c])) break iterateNodes;
            }
          }
        }
              
        console.log(curr, insertIndex, n);

        elem.find(curr).before($articleWithAd);

      }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="post-text">
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce eu accumsan dui. Sed molestie ac dolor venenatis tincidunt. Maecenas condimentum, diam at pellentesque pellentesque, massa dolor dignissim diam, nec mollis felis est non est. Vestibulum consectetur
    massa vel lectus porta, consequat venenatis odio pharetra. Integer a felis eget lectus tempus finibus nec a nulla. Nam leo metus, aliquet eleifend neque ut, tristique tristique mi. <a href="" class="asda asdasd asd asd asdasdasdsa sadasdasd asdasd asda asdasd asd asd asdasdasdsa sadasdasd asdasd asda asdasd asd asd asdasdasdsa sadasdasd asdasd ">Suspendisse potenti. Integer faucibus sollicitudin leo, vel ultrices nulla maximus vel.</a>    Vestibulum volutpat ligula sit amet nisi cursus aliquet. Quisque urna nisi, ullamcorper pretium volutpat non, porta non ligula. Integer nec turpis ut leo accumsan vestibulum.
  </p>
  <p>
    Nullam vitae orci metus. Nulla sit amet ipsum non sem tincidunt semper. Integer euismod dictum blandit. Vivamus eget molestie tellus, at porta purus. Duis vulputate, mi et fermentum aliquam, mi nisi convallis sapien, eu vehicula est mi et ex. Curabitur
    quam augue, tincidunt in orci ac, tempus imperdiet enim. Mauris nec sapien vehicula, vulputate lacus id, convallis urna. Aliquam tempor commodo erat.
  </p>
  <p>
    Morbi sit amet fermentum purus, ut pulvinar mi. Fusce nec sem enim. Fusce et nunc sodales mi dictum eleifend. Donec ornare molestie suscipit. Maecenas tempus urna nec elit aliquet, in iaculis augue malesuada. Cras vel imperdiet ante. Aenean nibh nibh,
    convallis vel arcu eget, placerat bibendum turpis.
  </p>
</div>
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/pv4m69jb/7/

Comment: @salivan _"yes but you loose all the html tags like this"_ What do you mean by "loose all the html tags"? Using `.text()` at `var $article = $('#post-text').text();` should only return `.textContent` of `#post-text`, instead of returning both `.textContent` and `.innerHTML` of `#post-text`. Do you also want to count the text of actual tags, including attributes, within `#post-text`

Comment: @salivan That is `<p>` is part of `.innerHTML` of `#post-text`, and should count as three characters? Or, do you only want to count the actual text content of `#post-text`?

Comment: No, issue is that in the final result `p a` all html tags are stripped. Notice that link is gone. I want to keep html tags not strip them.